# Table is full in Amazon RDS (MySQL), what can be the root cause?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm experiencing a problem with Amazon RDS. MySQL database size is 5Gb. I'm trying to insert new row into the table and I'm getting `Table is full` error. This is what `SHOW TABLE STATUS` gives for this table:

```
rows = 220801
avg_row_length = 1114
data_length = 246169600
index_length = 29048832
data_free = 3145728
```

What's going on? And why `data_free` is so low if my DB size is 5Gb?

ps. Full text of error sounds like `The table 'foo' is full {prepstmnt 850033372 INSERT INTO foo (text) VALUES (?) [params=(String) some text]} [code=1114, state=HY000]`

Comment: Please post the full output of `SHOW TABLE STATUS like 'foo'`

Comment: `data_free` is how much slack space is in the database file itself, it's normal for it to be only a few MB.  Large `data_free` values indicate wasted space.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MySQL 5.1?  It can only handle 1024 open write transactions and reports full table when the limit is exceeded: [Bug 26590](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=26590).  It's increased to 128K in 5.5.